# How to populate an SKShapeNode uniformly

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skshapenode

The code I am using to generate lines is so:

```
 func populate(num: Int) {
    for var i = 0; i < num; i++ {
        let lines = Line(size: CGSizeMake(lineWidth, lineHeight))
        let x = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(size.width * 20))) - size.width / 4
        let y = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(size.height * 90))) - size.height / 100
        lines.position = CGPointMake(x, y)
        addChild(lines)
        lines.zPosition = -1

    }
```

It populates just fine, but they are all randomly placed (I got this code from a tutorial). I would like to know if there is a way I can uniformly generate a line every x number of points without having to manually place them. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of         `let x = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(size.width * 20))) - size.width / 4
        let y = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(size.height * 90))) - size.height / 100` you define how you want your x to be placed,  for example:

```
let x = (i * size.width)
let y = 0
```

will place your lines in a single straight line along the x axis where y is 0

Comment: how can I test your code out lol  if you are getting errors it is probably due to casting concerns,  wrap the values in a CGFloat like `let x = CGFloat(i * size.width)`

Comment: Oh right. Well I thought it'd work just fine, but it gave me a "Binary operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type Int and CGFloat

Comment: That means you need to cast one of the variables , so `let x = CGFloat(i) * size.width`

Comment: Wonderful! Is there anyway I can change the distance between the lines?

Comment: you need to understand what your code is doing,  the x is where the line gets places,  you want to increase the distance,  increase the value of x